# Problems with geotools library to create a .jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, geotools

I have a java project and it works in eclipse then I create a .jar for this project and when a try to execute the jar the following errors appears:

1. If I create the .jar with eclipse:

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/data/FeatureSource
   ```
2. If I create the .jar with mvn: Error:

   ```
   no se ha encontrato o cargado la clase principal client.Client
   ```

Comment: By "no se ha encontrato o cargado la clase principal client.Client"* DYM: "not found or loaded main class client.Client"?  I got that from Google translate after changing one character in the string as suggested by them.  Please a) Do the translation yourself in future (to save others the trouble).  b) Always copy/paste error and exception output.

Answer (score 0):

1/ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/data/FeatureSource

you need to add the geotools jar in your classpath when you run your jar

2/ For the error when using maven, is there a Main-Class specified in the manifest ?

Show us  your META-INF\MANIFEST.MF file for both jars

Comment: This is the MANIFEST.MF:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_24 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: client/Client

Name: common
Specification-Title: JDBC
Specification-Version: 4.0
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Implementation-Title: MySQL Connector/J
Implementation-Version: 5.1.17
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.mysql
Implementation-Vendor: Oracle

Comment: The manifest says that the class containing your main method and thus starting your application is Client in package client.
Is that really the case ? when you start your application java complains that it can't find that class.